# how to extract data, convert it to ascii and push it in a list in javascript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I receive data from an external device in decimal values, that I need to convert in ascii and then push it in a list
data example:

```
#onData: 1,3,200,
  78,69,84,71,69,65,82,45,71,117,101,115,116,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  70,114,105,103,111,109,97,116,45,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,45,87,73,70,73,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  77,73,67,82,79,45,83,89,83,84,69,77,83,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  77,73,67,82,79,45,83,89,83,84,69,77,83,45,71,85,69,83,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  77,73,67,82,79,45,83,89,83,84,69,77,83,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,64,123
```

The first 3 elements of `#onData` need to be ignored and the last 2 elements as well.

In ascii it would be:

```
NETGEAR-Guest
Frigomat-12345678-WIFI
MICRO-SYSTEMS
MICRO-SYSTEMS-GUEST
MICRO-SYSTEMS
```

I have a method to convert:

```
arrayBuffer2str(buf) {
    var str = "";
    var ui8 = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (var i = 0; i < ui8.length; i++) {
      str = str + String.fromCharCode(ui8[i]);
    }
    return str;
  }
```

I would need to get rid of the zeros and then push it in an array of strings:

```
this.wifiNetworks.push("Network-1");
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract the buffer between two zeros and isolate the significant response, try this

```
let prevVal;
let phrase= [];
for (let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    let val = array[i];

    if (val == 0 && prevVal != 0) {
        // end of response
        process(phrase);
    }

    if (prevVal == 0 && val != 0) {
        // start new response
        phrase= [];
    }

    phrase.push(val);
    prevVal = val;
}

function process(phrase) {
    // TODO Process your phrase here and remove the inner zeros
}
```

Also, consider removing your zeros using the **.filter** function

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Assuming that we are getting the input as an array.

```
const inputArray = [1, 3, 200,
  78, 69, 84, 71, 69, 65, 82, 45, 71, 117, 101, 115, 116, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  70, 114, 105, 103, 111, 109, 97, 116, 45, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 45, 87, 73, 70, 73, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  77, 73, 67, 82, 79, 45, 83, 89, 83, 84, 69, 77, 83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  77, 73, 67, 82, 79, 45, 83, 89, 83, 84, 69, 77, 83, 45, 71, 85, 69, 83, 84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  77, 73, 67, 82, 79, 45, 83, 89, 83, 84, 69, 77, 83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 123];
const resultArray = [];
let stringIndex = 0;

for (i = 3; i <= inputArray.length - 3; i++) {
  if (inputArray[i] !== 0) {
    resultArray[stringIndex] = resultArray[stringIndex]
      ? resultArray[stringIndex].concat(String.fromCharCode(inputArray[i]))
      : ''.concat(String.fromCharCode(inputArray[i]));
  } else if (inputArray[i - 1] !== 0) {
    stringIndex = stringIndex + 1
  }
}

console.log(resultArray);
//  Add code to push the result to server,
```

The output would be

> [ 'NETGEAR-Guest',   'Frigomat-12345678-WIFI',   'MICRO-SYSTEMS',
>   'MICRO-SYSTEMS-GUEST',   'MICRO-SYSTEMS' ]